# Regexp to allow only digits, comma and dollar character

Tags: regex

I want a regexp which will allow only "**0-9**", "**,**", and "**$**".

For example: **$100,000**

But there could be just digits like **100** too.

Got expression:

```
/^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,9}(\,[0-9]{0,9})*(\,[0-9]{0,9})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1,9}(\,[0-9]{0,9})?|0(\,[0-9]{0,9})?|(\,[0-9]{1,9})?)$/
```

Also:

/^(\d+)*?(\$[0-9]{0,})*?(\,[0-9]{0,})*?$/

Comment: Can you show us a wider range of accepted inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  \$\d*\,?\d\d*
```

you can test you regexp on ligne like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) OR [regextester](http://www.regextester.com/)